# Intercept touch events in Navigation Drawer Header to allow RecyclerView to scroll?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-touch-event

I'm trying to add a mutable list of usernames to the header of a Navigation drawer. Once the height of the recyclerview exceeds the given dimension of the header, I am unable to access the hidden items in the recyclerview. I think I need to intercept the touch events from the DrawerLayout and pass them on to the header and the recycler view to allow it to scroll, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

Here is the Main Activity xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here is the nav_header_main.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/addUserLayout"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:text="@string/add_user"
    android:id="@+id/navbarAddUser"/>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rvUsers"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to construct a CustomDrawerLayout class to pass the touch events in the header to the headerview but it's not accomplishing what I want it to. Here is the onInterceptTouchEvent method from that class:

```
    @Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getChildAt(1);

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    final int action = ev.getAction();

    switch(action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            //if mouse is dragged we dont intercept
            if(ev.getY() < headerView.getHeight() + headerView.getY() &&
                    ev.getX() < headerView.getWidth() + headerView.getX() &&
                    ev.getX() > headerView.getX() &&
                    ev.getY() > headerView.getY()) {
                isScrolling = true;
                Log.d(TAG_DRAWERLAYOUT, "scrolling");
                return false;
            }
            if(isScrolling) {
                Log.d(TAG_DRAWERLAYOUT, "scrolling outside of header");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            isScrolling = false;
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! I'm pretty new to Android development and there's clearly still a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this a little more brought me to a decent workaround for my problem. Instead of putting the Navbar Header as a separate layout file, I included the items I wanted in the header as members of the body of the NavigationView. Then to move the menu content of the NavigationDrawer, I used a constraint layout with a transparent background and an equal height to the items in the body of the Navigation View.

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_blank">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_bottom_height"
        android:id="@+id/rvUsers"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_top_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/addUserLayout"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:text="@string/add_user"
    android:id="@+id/navbarAddUser"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

nav_header_main.xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="176dp"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```